# Is it possible to bind a socket to 2 adresses in c?

Tags: c, sockets, ipv6

I've to create a socket which listen from two IP adresses. is it possibile?

```
struct sockaddr_in6 bind_addr;
memset(&bind_addr, 0, sizeof(bind_addr));

bind_addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
bind_addr.sin6_port   = htons(9001);
bind_addr.sin6_addr   = in6addr_any;

if (bind(fd,(struct sockaddr *) &bind_addr,sizeof(bind_addr)) < 0) {
    perror("bind() failed");
    return -1;
}
```

I should need something like "in6addr_any", which listen from all the IPs but for two of them only.

Comment: Nope. Create two sockets.

Comment: No you can't bind a socket to multiple interfaces. If you need to bind to multiple interfaces, you need one socket per interface. It's easy to multiplex or poll multiple sockets though.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude seams nice to multiplexing or polling multiple sockets. any hints?

Comment: On POSIX-compatible systems you can use `poll` (or the older `select`) to watch multiple file descriptors.

Comment: The `select` function is traditional. And there's always the `poll` function. Then you have platform-specific functionality like `epoll` on Linux, `kqueue` on the BSD variants. Or signal-driven (POSIX `SIGIO`), or asynchronous functions. Or many other ways. There are also libraries which can abstract multiple ways into a single interface (`libev` for example). Good tutorials and books will be able to help you, as would some searching in a search engine.

Comment: Thanks so much Guys, your help was really apreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you have to use two different sockets for that; bind each socket to one of the addresses.